# Obtener Items seleccionados de ComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, mvvm

estoy trabajando con algunos controles de DevExpress y se me presentó un problema, quiero obtener los valores que se seleccionan del ComboBoxEdit que esta dentro de un ListView pero no lo consigo,agrego el código con el que estoy trabajando.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listCheck" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding MachineList}" SelectionChanged="listCheck_SelectionChanged" Background="White">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1F79CB" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LawnGreen" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <hw:VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="Control" Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="button">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DataTemplate >
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Nuevo" Margin="10" Style="{DynamicResource flatButtonStyleLogin}" MinWidth="100" Background="Transparent">
                                                        <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                            <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="Click" 
                                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.LoadCommand, 
                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" 
                                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                                        </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                    </Button>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger x:Name="combo" Binding="{Binding type}" Value="machine">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DataTemplate >
                                                    <Grid x:Name="gridCombo">
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Description}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Grid.Row="1" x:Name="checkedComboBox" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100"
                                                                ShowSizeGrip="False" 
                                                                DisplayMember="DescriptionShort" 
                                                                IsTextEditable="False"   
                                                                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ProcessTypeList,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                                                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                                                                <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings />
                                                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                                                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Has probado a hacer un binding de la propiedad `SelectedItem` del ComboboxEdit a una propiedad de tu viewmodel?

Comment: @Pikoh lo intenté pero no funcionó, ya pude resolverlo usando codebehind. Gracias